# Split a string into text and integer

Tags: string, pyhook

I have a string of the form

```
" This year is 2014"
```

I would like to split the string into two parts

```
part1="This year is"
part2="2014"
```

Comment: What is your question? How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split on whitespace followed by a digit, like this:

```
>>> part1, part2 = re.split(r'\s(?=\d)', " This year is 2014", 1)
>>> part1, part2
(' This year is', '2014')
```